# Filter value in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to see if filter area in a datable is empty or not and what is it's value?

I am using a datatable with pagination, when I add a new row to the datatable, I want to see if my rows are filtered or not to find the page in which newly added row is located.

Comment: The most simple solution is to client-side add some eventhandler that on 'change' and not empty adds some css to the inputs. It is a plain html issue then.

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje. Event handlers can be used to solve this problem, but primefaces has some special api for handling sorting state of the datatble. Isn't there any similar solution for filters?

Comment: Nope, sorry...But you can always file an issue to request this. Most of the time you'll visually see filters being populated, besides 'whitespace'. I therefore trim all the filter values before using them